# Analyzing RAM dump in Android

Tags: android, kernel, ram, panic

In case of Kernel Panic in Android we dump all RAM data in a file. In this case RAM addresses are Physical addresses. But in logs if we print address of any variable then that address is Virtual address. From dump if I want to know what data is stored in that virtual address (printed via logs) then how can I get that information from RAM dump.

Also is there any Swap area like thing in Android? Swap concept is in Linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

you program running in user mode should not cause Kernel Panic, but application crash.
anyhow kernel development is completely different, I think the physical address for virtual address should be found in the process's page table.